# Remove all excessive line breaks at end of cell

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets i am using the function TRIM() to remove leading and trailing spaces in text, but I also want to remove line breaks at the end of each cell/text, basically excessive line breaks that were left there by mistake or w/e. Is there a way to go about this?

Posting picture that shows what I want.
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample spreadsheet to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention:

> basically excessive line breaks

**Using `TRIM` removes trailing spaces AND trailing line breaks.**

It even removes both if they happen to coexist.

On your example it is the height of neighbour cell that cause the result.

Test your results in a different sheet.

*You can use a formula like:*

```
=INDEX(TRIM('Sheet 1'!A2:A9))
```

Please take a look at an **example of how TRIM works**

[image: example of how TRIM works]

As [stated](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140), the **`TRIM`** function

> *Removes leading, trailing and repeated spaces in text.*

---

**Functions used**:
[TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)
[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
[TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Comment: One could [also make use of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEDhG.png) `REGEXREPLACE` to remove empty lines `=INDEX(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B2:E2,"\n{2,}",CHAR(10))))`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1; CHAR(10); ))
```

for array:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10; CHAR(10); )))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegexReplace like so:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D3,"\n","")
```